# Use Babel Transform inside of React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, babeljs, babel-core

I'm trying to convert a string to valid JSX code, and then inject it into my React component.

```
const babel = require('babel-core')
let result = eval(babel.transform('<p className="greeting">Hello</p>').code)
```

But am getting hit with a wall of errors, because I'm trying to use Babel in the browser:

```
ERROR in ./~/babel-core/lib/api/node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/ben/Desktop/Work/code/ru-coding-challege/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api'
 @ ./~/babel-core/lib/api/node.js 72:10-23
 @ ./~/babel-core/index.js
 @ ./src/js/containers/app-container.js
 @ ./src/js/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/js/index.js

...more similar errors
```

Yes, I know creating code from a string and injecting it is **frowned upon**, but D3 creates elements dynamically (i.e. you can't write them declaratively) For example: axes whose values and number of ticks change based on the data. I've successfully changed the D3 axes into JSX with [htmltojsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmltojsx) but that returns a `String`. I need to turn that `String` into valid JSX components that I can inject into my code.

EDIT: As Michael Lyons states below, I could just use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but I am trying to avoid this option unless everything else doesn't work. Trying to stay within the React paradigm as much as possible.

Here's how my component's render method would look:

```
<svg width='100%' height='600'>
  <g transform='translate(50, 50)'>
    <path d='...' className='path-0'></path>
  </g>
  {/* Insert JSX elements here. e.g. axes below */}
  {axes}
</svg>
```

And here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/html/index.html' }
    ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      IN_BROWSER: true,
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is this JSX code actually coming from? What you have will try to compile it when the user loads the page, which means you're trying to bundle and ship the entirety of Babel to your users client-side, which is terrible.

Comment: You could just use the HTML output from D3 and dangerously set the inner html of a wrapper div that's in a component. Check this link: [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: @loganfsmyth - As I said above, the JSX code is coming from `htmltojsx`, which I'm on the output of D3. If there's another way to transpile D3 output to valid JSX, I'd love to learn about it.

Comment: @MichaelLyons - I thought about using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but I'm trying to avoid that route since at least by transpiling to JSX, I still somewhat use the React approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of translating HTML to JSX, then rendering with babel in your code while on the client, you could render that html directly through your React component.

Facebook's DOM element implementation has built in functionality for this use-case, and you are right it is generally frowned upon for security reasons because it opens up vulnerabilities to [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Facebook has even labeled it "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" to remind devs that this is dangerous.

So if you have HTML in a string format, you can render that in JSX in a manner such as this:

```
getMarkup() {
  return { __html: '<p class="greeting">Hello</p>' }
}
render() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getMarkup()} />;
}
```

This comes straight from the React DOM elements documentation here: [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

This method should also allow you to bypass having to convert your d3 output to JSX

Edit: Introductory sentence

Comment: I thought about using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but I'm trying to avoid that route since at least by transpiling to JSX, I still somewhat use the React approach. If nothing else really works, then I'll fall back to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`