# Is it possible to add JSX to React code dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Say I wanted to create a tree of JSX tags dynamically inside of a Javascript function, and then add them to my React code. Is that possible? If so, how would you do it?

EDIT: I am receiving `<div className="msg"><p>Hello World</p></div>` as a String, so I can't just return it without the quotation marks. Also, not using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

**JSX Factory**

```
function jsxFactory() {
  return '<div className="msg"><p>Hello World</p></div>'
}
```

**React Code**

```
render() {
  render(
    {jsxFactory()}
  )
}
```

Comment: There is no simple solution to that. I think more context is needed.

Comment: The `React` API definition does not allow this because it opens up XSS attacks. There are plenty or react+d3 libs to look at and see how they work http://www.reactd3.org/

Comment: @BlairAnderson React-D3 is being deprecated - authors state that they can no longer maintain it (in the Readme). Also, React-D3 removes a lot of control from the author, due to the intricacies of D3. `react-faux-dom` is also not ideal. Was looking for another way that didn't use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without the quotes.

```
return <div className="msg"><p>Hello World</p></div>
```

Comment: In addition to that, the rendering code would have to be changed to `return jsxFactory()`.

Comment: If I received this code as a string e.g. `<div className="..."></div>`, how would I change it to be something that's returnable and usable in the code?

Comment: @BenGrunfeld https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @BenGrunfeld: It's possible, but not convenient. You'd have to include/bundle Babel to convert the JSX to valid JavaScript first and then `eval` the result. If the string contains HTML instead, then @Dave's link works.

Comment: @FelixKling Tried that. Babel breaks when you try to use it inside of react code. Even the import statement is enough to break the code.

Comment: @BenGrunfeld: I have successfully used Babel to compile user provided code on the fly in an React application, so it's certainly possible.

Comment: Here is another question I asked about htis subject, but felt maybe I could ask it a different way: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667083/use-babel-transform-inside-of-react-code/43667467#43667467](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667083/use-babel-transform-inside-of-react-code/43667467#43667467)

Comment: @BenGrunfeld: Setting the HTML is certainly less clowny then trying to transpile the string with Babel on the client and evaling it.

Comment: @FelixKling What can I say? I must be a clown. ;) Just trying to find a respectable way to integrate D3 into React when dynamic elements are returned from D3 generators (i.e. you can't write them declaratively).

Comment: @BenGrunfeld: I hope this didn't come across as offensive :) But just in general, running Babel on the client is something you don't want to do in a normal "app". AFAIK, D3 is very modular and can give you just the *data* you need without actually creating any markup. That might be the way to go in your case.

Comment: @FelixKling My pride is a little bruised, but my red nose hides it ;) Learned the hard way re not using Babel on the client side. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BenGrunfeld: You're welcome. If it helps, I feel like I'm doing clowny things all the time ;)

Comment: That's what makes programming fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly need to inject HTML embedded in a string you'll need [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), roughly:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: '<div className="msg"><p>Hello World</p></div>'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to specify that I have to do it without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: @BenGrunfeld Why on earth would you want to dangerously-set inner-HTML without using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`? **It's dangerous.**

Comment: Because the output is coming from a library I trust - i.e. D3. Trying to transpile D3 output into valid JSX and use D3 while staying inside of the React paradigm.

Comment: @BenGrunfeld What does that have to do with using/not-using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`? Whether or not the source is trusted, this is still the way to do it. But there are multiple ways to interface D3 to React that shouldn't require grabbing HTML and wedging it into the DOM, like https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3 or https://oli.me.uk/2015/09/09/d3-within-react-the-right-way/ etc.

Comment: React-D3 is being deprecated, and there are issues with `react-faux-dom`. Was just trying to find another way.

Comment: You can still use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.